# Is it possible to overload a terraform module?

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to overload a terraform module?

I am calling a module that creates a GKE cluster and node pool. This module is missing options to specify GPU and gVisor capabilities. I am wondering if it is possible to overload a module? basically I want to add/append more configs to the resources the module is creating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can copy the module and then modify to meet your requirements (if the license allows).

Comment: No, this is not possible. You also cannot "overload" a resource (which currently exists in similar DSLs e.g. Puppet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform's language favors [composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html) over inheritence/extension, so there is no mechanism to do exactly what you proposed.

Instead, the typical answer is to refactor the single large module into two or more smaller modules, and then have the calling configuration compose those smaller modules together to produce the desired effect. Ideally, if a caller finds that one of the smaller modules doesn't suit their needs then they can replace just that one module -- either with another module serving a similar purpose or with inline `resource`/`data` blocks -- but keep using the other modules.

In the specific example you gave, it seems like there might be a distinction to be made between the GKE cluster and its associated node pool. A possible new design would be a module that *only* declares a GKE cluster, and then either inline `resource` blocks to declare nodes to register with that cluster or potentially several modules that encapsulate different *kinds* of node pool, if your architecture includes a fixed set of node archetypes.

With that said, if the module you are using is a third-party one then your only options are to either use it as its author intended or to write your own module, possibly derived from the original one. Creating your own "fork" of the module will ensure that future changes to the original module can't invalidate the changes you've made.